# Quasi-hereditary algebras

Tags: reference-request, ring-theory, representation-theory, modules, algebras

Can anyone  please recommend a reference (I prefer a book chapter) on [Quasi-hereditary algebras](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-33/issue-2/Quasi-hereditary-algebras/10.1215/ijm/1255988725.full)? and if it is possible tell me how to prove that Schur algebras are Quasi-hereditary (or any other example, I just one to see one example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also found [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.17.1456&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and it contains some nice examples on quasi-hereditary algebras.

Answer (score 5):

It can be founded in the appendix of 'Finite Dimensional Algebras' by Drozd and Krichenko.